# задача "три монеты" из соревнования по программированию

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада, бинарный-поиск

я пока новичок и столкнулся с сложной для меня задачей на бинарный поиск. Думал простые будут...Может быть у меня просто теории недостаточно. Если это так то напишите.

Мне нужен алгоритм решения, который я пойму. Код сам напишу.

ссылка на задачу из acmp:
https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=1&id_section=3&id_topic=37&id_problem=1840

Это интерактивная задача.

Перед вами стопка из N монет. В стопке есть все монеты номиналов от 1 до N, причём они упорядочены по возрастанию сверху-вниз. То есть, верхняя монета номиналом 1, а нижняя — N. Вес каждой монеты равен её номиналу. Некто заменил ровно три монеты в стопке на фальшивые — вес таких монет равен нулю. Вы можете спрашивать суммарный вес первых K монет сверху для любого 0 ≤ K ≤ N.

Определите номиналы фальшивых монет не более чем за 32 вопроса, и тогда Некто подарит вам всю стопку монет.

Протокол взаимодействия
Вначале на ввод подаётся число N — количество монет (3 ≤ N ≤ 109). Далее ваша программа должна выводить запросы вида «? K», где 0 ≤ K ≤ N. В ответ вы получите сумму весов первых K монет вверху стопки.

Как только ваша программа будет готова сообщить ответ, выведите «! A B C», где 1 ≤ A, B, C ≤ N — различные номиналы фальшивых монет. После этого программа должна завершить работу.

Пример
стандартный ввод

```
6
12
6
6
2
2
0
0
```

стандартный вывод

```
? 6
? 5
? 4
? 3
? 2
? 1
? 0
! 1 5 3
```

Comment: Сначала решите аналогичную задачу с 2 фальшивыми монетами.

Comment: я могу решить такую но на третью просто не хватает запросов

Comment: Сколько запросов Вам надо для двух монет и N = 10^9 ?

Comment: за 32 запроса из 10^9 монет могу найти первую монету и соответственноо вторую т.к. знаю всю сумму и первую монету. Но это при условии, что фальшивых монет всего 2

Comment: 32 запроса. В условии написано

Comment: 32 для двух монет - явно много. Ведь если запросить вес полустопки, которая захватывает обе монеты, становится известна не только полустопка, в которой искать, но и сумма номеров монет. Так что поиск - ни разу не бинарный.

Comment: я не понял почему много. Что можно сделать зная сумму номеров монет?

Comment: Как минимум поделить всю часть на три области где не искать сначала, где не искать с конца, где искать в середине.

Comment: Не понял зачем делить на 3 области. Запросов всё равно 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диапазон 1..4 рассматриваем отдельно, чтобы сэкономить один вызов. Делаем вызов для 4, и в случае сомнительных сумм ещё один вызов для 1.

Пойдём бинарным поиском с увеличивающимся шагом, начиная с 4: делаем запросы для 8, 16, 32... монет. Итого 28 шагов до 2<sup>30</sup>.

Почему так? Если отсутствуют монеты в диапазоне D: lo=2<sup>k</sup>+1..hi=2<sup>k+1</sup>, то никакая монета из диапазона не может быть суммой двух других.

Вычисляем нехватку `s` на данном диапазоне.

```
 sm = sum(l[:hi])
 calls += 1
 s = hi * (hi+1) // 2 - sm
```

Если отсутствует одна монета, то `s<=hi`, мы сразу видим её номинал. Заносим в результат, исправляем ноль на значение `s`, чтобы дальнейшим вычислениям не мешало.

Иначе в диапазоне несколько нулей.

Если `s > 2*hi`, то в диапазоне три нуля.

Делаем запрос по элементу `pivot=s/3`.
Если недостача слева `slo` больше, чем справа `shi`, то слева от `pivot` (включая его) два нуля, справа один, и его позиция `shi` известна. Уточняем позиции слева, делая запрос по `slo/2`. Аналогично для `shi>slo`. Расчёт окончен.

Если `s` находится в пределах от `hi+1 до 2*hi`, то случай сложный. Может быть как 2 нуля, так и три

```
D = 17..32 
s = 57 = 17+18+22 = 17+19+21 = 18+19+20 = 25+32 = 26+31 = 27+30 = 28+29
```

Выполняем деление по `pivot=s/2`.

Если недостачи слева и справа `slo`, `shi` меньше или равны `hi`, то найдена пара нулей

Иначе нуля три, и выполняем ещё одно деление по `s/3` и действуем, как описано раньше для трёх монет.

Алгоритм на случайных тестах и вручную заданных сложных случаях работает, количество проверок не превышает `log(n)+2` (32 для 2^30).

Comment: Списибо,помог,но я делил попалам. Помог мне тем что можно за 2 запроса определить 3 монеты, если  попал между монетами

Comment: Отлично, если помогло. Вы только в следующий раз в вопросе приводите свои попытки, а то и вас заминусовали, и отвечающих обоих какой-то долбочудень заминусовал  ;))

Answer (score 2):

Просто как идея:

1. Запрашиваете вес всех монет. Смотрите, какого веса не хватает. Это пусть будет вес X = a+b+c

Если X меньше, чем N, то интервал X,N можно выкинуть из поиска навсегда. Например, если не хватает чисел 1, 2, 3 (то есть их сума равне 6), а всего чисел 100, то нет смысла что то искать в интервале (6, 100)

2. Двоичным поиском находите любую точку K, где не хватает другого числа Y < X

Тут надо иметь ввиду, что в процессе поиска можно отсечь какой то участок и в нем дальше не искать никогда. Например, если на N/2 нехватка веса также X, то всю область от N/2 до N можно исключить. Если на N/2 нехватки веса нет совсем, то можно исключить диапазон от 0 до N/2 из любых дальнейших поисков.

3. Остается найти точку, где не хватает веса Z, Z<X, Z!=Y. Эта точка будет с одной из сторон от точки K.

Имея X, Y, Z и зная, что X=a+b+c и что одна из (Y,Z)=a+b, другая просто (Y,Z)=b, можно легко вычислить a, b, c.